# PHP Bug in String Concatenation or am i wrong?

Tags: php

i allways thought, that the Concatenation Dot is to combine multiline-Strings. But today i ran into trouble doing the following:

```
if (strlen($col->getValue())>$col->getLength())
          $this->errors[]=$name." ist ".
          strlen($col->getValue())-$col->getLength().
          " too much chars!";
```

i thought this to be one single line after the if-clause, but PHP evaluated line 2 and 3 after the if even when the condition wasn't given here. I needed to do some

```
if (strlen($col->getValue())>$col->getLength()) {
          $this->errors[]=$name." ist ".
          strlen($col->getValue())-$col->getLength().
          " Zeichen zu lang!";
}
```

brackets around to get correct result instead of strange Parser errors. Am i understanding the concatenation-Sign usage wrong? I noticed the same when creating multi-line constants in classes ( i.E. prepared SQL Statements).

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong here. Any point i haven't seen?

Comment: @crypticツ strlen returns an int - why use -> on an int!?

Comment: @Philipp sorry just saw that =o)

Comment: I don't think that things are that easy! The question is why is a string assigned = string . expression . string; spreaded over three lines not a single expression! I do not agree that this question is too localized. I think it's worth an answer, so thank you for closing down instead of answering guys! great job!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put parens around this expression:

```
(strlen($col->getValue())-$col->getLength())
```

Comment: this is what i've done too! It was my very first idea, but that won't help either!

Comment: damned you are right ;-) i just re-did what i tried yesterday with simple strings instead of object attributes. And the Netbeans IDE simply shows the answer (strlen($col->getValue())-$col->getLength() evaluates to an INT and the DOT after the INT just makes it a float and thus crushes the concatenation!

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using the horrible practice of not using braces with your `if`. Only the first line following the condition is considered part of the condition.

Comment: when it's just one line that follows if or else, it's easier to read. In this case where the line got by far to long you are right! I just wonder why the concatenation-sign doesn't work here. Concidering your Critcism on style i do agree, but this isn't my question here. I know that it is bad style when having more then one following line!

Comment: No, its bad style always... because it can lead to mistakes similar to this. Better to just never do it :-)

Comment: what else can i say, but you are right ;-) and IDEs always introduce the bracktes for us. I'll try to let them where they are - promised !